# Is there any way to see what is causing the system to freeze?

Tags: crash

My system has been freezing and I have to restart the PC pressing the power button and turn in it off, I think that is a fatal crash, I'm using mostly Google Chrome when this happen but I have tried some steps that I found here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054738/ubuntu-18-04-freezes-while-im-using-chrome but it didn't work... Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't get any response and are forced to reboot, then after the system comes back up, you can look at various log files in /var/log such as /var/log/syslog and scroll up to the time before you rebooted and look for any events that could indicate a problem causing the freeze.

Besides syslog in /var/log there's kernlog and Xorg.0.log which may offer up clues.

Comment: Thanks, I will try next time it happens

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into TTY (virtual terminal) and enter:

killall chrome
Though you might need to use 'chromium' instead (I use firefox and it works for me)

This might keep you from having to reboot each time, just restart Chrome.

Comment: I have tried to enter the virtual terminal (I guess you refer to Crt+Alt F1) but I can't even move the pointer and the keyboard don't even respond. so it never enter to the VT so the only option that I have it's to turn it off by pressing the power button for 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a long shot guess but I used the application from the app center called Monitor and had issues with it locking my system on both my Macbook Pro and Huawei laptops. If you happen to be using it then I would suggest uninstalling it and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: actually I have that application but if I not mistaken the problem started before install that app, actually I installed it to know which app was using to much memory on my system (off course it is Chrome).... I have also tried to test the system make it run out of memory but it is just randomly that it happens